# Windows Amazon Machine Image (AMI) doesn't remember password for new instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

If I start a windows EC2 and run `net user Administrator "new_password"` I can thereafter RDP in with that new password.

However, when I create an AMI from that box, and fire up a new EC2 from that AMI, the password I set doesn't work for the new instance, which is surprising.

How can I get the password to stick? Currently I have to login the first time with the `.pem` file and then set the password manually using the original line of code above). I would like to simply be able to use the password I set on the original box from which the AMI was created

## What I've tried

I tried selecting a non-default 'Proceed without a key pair' option when launching the AMI, but the password I had previously set did not work

[image]

Comment: Related: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/sysprep-create-install-ec2-windows-amis/

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. It looks like that method sets a random Administrator password? The opposite of what I'm after. Unless I've missed something?

Comment: Yes, but it's a starting point for digging into the process for forcing a new, random password or not (i.e. re-using the existing password).

Answer (score 1):

From [Configuring a Windows Instance Using EC2Launch - Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud](https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2launch.html):

> Update the following settings as needed and save your changes. Provide a password in adminPassword only if `adminPasswordtype` is `Specify`.

```
{
  "setComputerName": false,
  "setWallpaper": true,
  "addDnsSuffixList": true,
  "extendBootVolumeSize": true,
  "handleUserData": true,                      
  "adminPasswordType": "Random | Specify | DoNothing",
  "adminPassword":  "password that adheres to your security policy (optional)"
}
```

> The password types are defined as follows:
>
> **Random:** 
>   EC2Launch generates a password and encrypts it using the user's key. The system disables this setting after the instance is launched so that this password persists if the instance is rebooted or stopped and started.
>
> **Specify:**
>   EC2Launch uses the password you specify in adminPassword. If the password does not meet the system requirements, EC2Launch generates a random password instead. The password is stored in LaunchConfig.json as clear text and is deleted after Sysprep sets the administrator password. EC2Launch encrypts the password using the user's key.
>
> **DoNothing:**
>   EC2Launch uses the password you specify in the unattend.xml file. If you don't specify a password in unattend.xml, the administrator account is disabled.

Comment: Thanks John. To clarify, do I provide the `adminPasswordType` and `adminPassword` parameters when launching the instance from the AMI, or before then somehow? Also, I'm launching from a lambda and it doesn't seem wise to have a plaintext admin password in a lambda function..?

Comment: You would put this configuration on the instance itself. You'll need to login and modify the configuration file. Prior to Windows 2016, the old `Ec2Config` had a checkbox that you could simply turn off from within the instance, but I don't know if that is present in `EC2Launch` for Windows 2016.